# Mysql Select reciprocal pairs of records, without duplicates

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table with two columns:

1. person_id
2. person_id with whom 1st field id is in cooperation

I need to select all cooperation pairs, it is easy but in what is the problem:
table have data like: `987` - `102`, `103 - 104`, `104 - 103`, `21 - 102`. 
As the result with such data i should have 3 cooperation pairs `987 - 102`, `103-104`, `21-102`, as you see `103 - 104` and `104 - 103` records have the same logic, how can I avoid duplicating of them. Any idea?

Thanks, and best regards. Anton.

Comment: PERSON_ID int(10) , QUESTION_ID int(10)  TEXT_ANSWER text, i think second colomn is not need, because in that question, i use it in WHERE clause

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use MySQL's [`LEAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) functions, together with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(a, b), GREATEST(a, b) FROM mytable
```

Comment: if you have only the pair `(2,1)` it will output it as `(1,2)`

Comment: @alfasin: The problem description implies they are equivalent.  Otherwise, the OP should clarify how it was decided which of `(103,104)` and `(104,103)` should be kept and which discarded.

Comment: @eggyall: you are correct, no indication is given as to how the determination was made that `(103,104)` should be returned instead of `(104,103)`.  But preserving the order of the elements in the other "pairs" could be important in some cases.  As one example, if this result set (subquery) is joined to the table again, to get other columns from the row. Bottom line is that the order of the elements in the pair could be important (and we aren't told that it isn't.) The specification gives an example resultset. Your query returns a resultset that differs from the specification.

Comment: @spencer7593: You make a fair point--but whilst the OP didn't state it explicitly, my reading of the problem as stated remains that `(a,b)=(b,a)` and all such pairs should be returned no more than once.  If that isn't the case, then your proposed answer is a good suggestion.

Comment: @eggyal: I'd upvote your answer again if I could, because it's the most elegant approach to returning a distinct set of "pairs".

Comment: @spencer7593: Elegant perhaps, but not especially index-friendly.  Your approach will probably be more performant as the table grows.

Answer (score 3):

If preserving the order of the elements in each "pair" is **not** important, see the answer from eggyal.  That query returns a result set that is slightly different than the one you specified, it returns pair `102-987` instead of `987-102`. It also eliminates any "duplicate" pairs that appear in the table.

If preserving the order of the elements in each pair **is** important, and you want to return the "smaller - larger" rather than "larger - smaller" when both of those "matching" pairs are present, the you can use something like this:

```
SELECT c.col1, c.col2
  FROM mytable c
  LEFT
  JOIN mytable d ON d.col1 = c.col2 AND d.col2 = c.col1 AND d.col1 <> d.col2
 WHERE (d.col1 IS NULL OR d.col1 > c.col1)
```

To eliminate all duplicate pairs AND "matching" pairs, add a GROUP BY clause or the DISTINCT keyword, e.g.

```
SELECT c.col1, c.col2
  FROM mytable c
  LEFT
  JOIN mytable d ON d.col1 = c.col2 AND d.col2 = c.col1 AND d.col1 <> d.col2
 WHERE (d.col1 IS NULL OR d.col1 > c.col1)
 GROUP BY c.col1, c.col2
```

**NOTES:**

SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d9e7/1 and here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d9e7/2

The comparison operators are not null-safe, they may not return the resultset you want when either col1 or col2 contains a NULL value.  (The query could be modified to handle NULL values for col1 and/or col2.) As written, both queries would return, for example, both `(1,NULL)` and `(NULL,1)` if those "matching" "pairs" are in the table.  (It boils down to the question of whether you want to consider NULL values to match or not.)

Also note, both queries will return rows where `col1=col2`.

Note the first query does NOT eliminate "duplicate" rows that exist in the table. That is, if a duplicate "pair" e.g `(202,101)` appears in two different rows, then both will be returned (unless the query returns at least one row with a "matching" pair: `(101,202)`.)

It wasn't clear what result set you wanted returned in those cases, so the first query shows the pattern for eliminating ONLY rows `(larger,smaller)` when a matching `(smaller,larger)` pair is in the resultset.

The second query eliminates ALL duplicates and "matching" pairs.