# De-duplicating many-to-many relationships in MySQL lookup table

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, unique

I've inherited a database that includes a lookup table to find other patents that are related to a given patent.

So it looks like

```
╔════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║ patent_id ║ related_id ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1  ║     1     ║     2      ║
║ 2  ║     1     ║     3      ║
║ 3  ║     2     ║     1      ║
║ 4  ║     2     ║     3      ║
║ 5  ║     3     ║     2      ║
╚════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

And I want to filter out the reciprocal relationships. 1->2 and 2->1 are the same for my purposes so I only want 1->2.

I don't need to make the edit in the table, I just need a query the returns a list of the unique relationships, and while I'm sure it's simple I've been banging my head against the keyboard for far too long.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql Select reciprocal pairs of records, without duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298702/mysql-select-reciprocal-pairs-of-records-without-duplicates)

Comment: Ah yep, thanks @TimBiegeleisen. I searched but somehow missed that one. I'll try that answer tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: Use this `SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(patent_id, related_id), GREATEST(patent_id, related_id) FROM mytable`

Comment: This ended up being the simplest answer for what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a clever query which you can try using.  The general strategy is to identify the unwanted duplicate records and then subtract them away from the entire set.

```
SELECT t.id, t.patent_id, t.related_id
FROM t LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.patent_id AS t1_patent_id, t1.related_id AS t1_related_id
    FROM t t1 LEFT JOIN t t2
    ON t1.related_id = t2.patent_id
    WHERE t1.patent_id = t2.related_id AND t1.patent_id > t1.related_id
) t3
ON t.patent_id = t3.t1_patent_id AND t.related_id = t3.t1_related_id
WHERE t3.t1_patent_id IS NULL
```

Here is the inner temporary table generated by this query.  You can convince yourself that by applying the logic in the `WHERE` clause you will select the correct records.  Non-duplicate records are characterized by `t1.patent_id` != `t2.related_id`, and all these records are retained.  In the case of duplicates (`t1.patent_id` = `t2.related_id`), the record chosen from each pair of duplicates is the one where `patent_id` < `related_id`, as you requested in your question.

```
╔════╦══════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════╗  
║ id ║ t1.patent_id ║ t1.related_id ║ t2.patent_id ║ t2.related_id ║
╠════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1  ║      1       ║       2       ║      2       ║       1       ║ * duplicate
║ 1  ║      1       ║       2       ║      2       ║       3       ║
║ 2  ║      1       ║       3       ║      3       ║       2       ║
║ 3  ║      2       ║       1       ║      1       ║       2       ║ * duplicate
║ 3  ║      2       ║       1       ║      1       ║       3       ║
║ 4  ║      2       ║       3       ║      3       ║       2       ║ * duplicate
║ 5  ║      3       ║       2       ║      2       ║       1       ║
║ 5  ║      3       ║       2       ║      2       ║       3       ║ * duplicate
╚════╩══════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Click the link below for a running example of this query.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/673b06/10)

Comment: I ended up going with the solution you commented above (as outlined in  [Mysql Select reciprocal pairs of records, without duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298702/mysql-select-reciprocal-pairs-of-records-without-duplicates) ), but I'm curious about how this compares performance-wise with that option.

Comment: I would also go with the simpler option.  I posted this as an alternative for information.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
select distinct * from
(select patient_id, related_id from TABLENAME
 union
select related_id, patient_id from TABLENAME
);
```

Okay you're right the above won't work. Try

```
select patient_id, related_id from TABLENAME p1
where p1.patiend_id not in 
    (select patient_id from TABLENAME p2
     where p2.related_id = p1.related_id)
```

Comment: So I was thinking about something like this, but it just puts me back where I started.  If I have a list that contains 2->1 and 1->2, adding the reciprocals gives me 2->1, 1->2, 1->2, and 2->1. Distincting that just puts be back at the start.

Comment: Try my modified answer above. I'm not near a DB right now so no way to try it out.